# Direct object for the verb "imbue" that isn't on this list

Tags: word-choice

I originally posted [this question on RPG StackExchange](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/34156/4563), as my use of the word would be for a custom Dungeons & Dragons class. There weren't a lot of thoughts there, so I thought I'd try here.

Fill in the blank:

#### Someone *imbues* a __________ on an object, giving it magic powers.

I need a word that serves as the direct object in this sentence, but there are a lot of caveats on the sort of word I need.

Some background: in D&D, there are a number of different "types" of magical ability, and to keep things straight each one has various terms associated with it, most importantly a verb and an object. For example, you might say someone

- *casts* a *spell*
- *manifests* a *power*, and may *augment* that *power* as well
- *invokes* an *invocation*
- *initiates* a *maneuver*
- *utters* a *true name*
- *infuses* an *infusion*
- *activates* a *magic item*
- *binds* a *vestige* (in the game, a sort of spirit)
- *hexes* (someone with) a *curse*

This is just a fairly simple way to keep the different types separate, which is important because they behave differently under the rules. So if we say someone *casts* something, we know to look at the rules for *spells,* etc.

So I need a word that fits well in this pattern, but doesn't use one of those already-taken words. It also shouldn't refer to, or appear to refer to, existing game-terms, like

- arcana
- artifact
- conjuration
- effect
- enhancement
- enchantment
- sorcerer
- transmutation
- wizard
- witch

RPG SE came up with "imbuement," which... I do not care for in the least.

I'm not exactly tied to the word *imbue* so alternatives are acceptable if they come with a good object. For reference, the magic would be used to improve or augment items.

Along those lines, RPG SE suggested *endow/endowment* (which sounds either collegial or phallic and neither is what I'm going for), *empower/empowerment* (little better than imbuement), *bewitch/bewitchment* (confusing since there is a witch class), and *ensorcell/ensorcellation* or *ensorcell/ensorceration* (again, might be confused with the sorcerer class).

Don't let the fixation on having the object be the noun-form of the verb confuse you; that may be a desirable (ish) property, but it's not necessary (see *cast* a *spell*).

Comment: It’s quite difficult to distill a concrete question from your posting. What is it?

Comment: @tchrist What is the best word to use as the direct object of "someone imbues a _____," that fits the patterns and norms of the context without conflicting with already-used terms.

Comment: Does "Effect" work? Usually, imbuing something with another thing, when dealing with games, results in an effect being added to the object, whether good or bad.

Comment: @JonathanSpirit Ah, knew I was forgetting an obvious term. Sorry, yeah, that's taken too. Will add it to the list.

Comment: @tchrist I've restructured to try to make the actual question stand out more; let me know if that's better or not.

Comment: It’s good to have it up front like that. But I do not know the answer.

Comment: @KRyan After searching for various synonyms of the word "enhancement", words you can use include: Intensification, amplification, magnification, or augmentation.

Comment: (From the OED) From L. _imbuere, imbutum_ 'to wet, moisten, tinge, stain, imbrue, imbue'. English senses: (1) v tr To saturate, wet thoroughly (with moisture); to dye, tinge, impregnate (with colour or some physical quality). (1b) To imbrue (with blood). (2) 2. To impregnate, permeate, pervade, or inspire (with opinions, feelings, habits, etc.). Hence _imbuement_, the action of imbuing, the fact of being imbued.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm aware it exists, and directly address it in the question. I simply do not like the word. My use of *imbue*, by the way, would be the "to dye, tinge, impregnate (with colour or some physical quality)," one.

Comment: This suggests involvement with potions or other wet and smeary things like blood or ichor, possibly with psychoactive chemomagical effects.

Comment: @JonathanSpirit Augmentation is used, and the others... focus too much on improving something, when these powers could be used to add entirely new qualities or properties

Comment: @JohnLawler Do note that he said "RPG SE came up with "imbuement," which... I do not care for in the least."

Comment: @KRyan Try Accretion, which means addition or gradual growth.

Comment: What about gloss (or shimmer or sheen)? _Player 2 imbues a gloss on your underpants of protection; attacks by the spear of impalement now bounce off you_.

Comment: I am confused why all these suggestions are comments rather than answers. At any rate, none of them has so far been "aha, that's it!" for me, though I like a few.

Comment: Probably because your question doesn't have 'one answer', while it's all done in comments there is some degree of _you'll improve your question to fit the ELU requirements_ where an answer instead of an offering/opinion/guess can be made. You'd be wise to imbue yourself with the gloss of carefreeness in preparation for the closing of your question as off-topic, opinion based, looking for a word for software and/or any number of other reasons.

Comment: @Frank I suppose so; there is unfortunately not a lot I can do to narrow things down (if there were, I most likely would have found my answer), so I suppose there's just not a solid SE-style question to be had here.

Comment: Probably not but you might as well keep trying until the closure happens, you never know your question might have been _imbued with a sheen of longevity_.

Comment: Why does it have to have a separate direct object at all?  Why not say, "Player 2 imbues 'Acid Immunity' (or whatever the special attribute is) on your Underpants of Protection."

Comment: I'm not used to seeing the verb 'imbue' other than in the passive. 'He was imbued with a passion for sport'. I would feel quite awkward using it as an active verb.

Comment: @Jim Because it becomes very difficult to write concise rules about effects of this sort if effects of this sort don't have a name.

Comment: @WS2 Might just be a thing in fantasy literature and gaming, but I see it used in this sense quite often.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm not sure what your suggestion there is. The term would be used outside that singular sentence, so restructuring the sentence to make it unnecessary doesn't help me. If you meant to suggest *magic powers,* there are far too many other ways to put magic on items in the game to claim that term globally.

Comment: Just following on from "activates a magic item"... so you "imbue an item with magic powers"?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I guess, in addition to be too opinion-based, the question is also unclear. Whatever noun I choose, it needs to be one I can refer to and have everyone reading know I mean this system. *Magic powers* could also be any of the other ways to put magic on items.

Comment: **aura** deserves to be mentioned here.  It works better for an item that ehances a trait - "aura of dexterity" than a transformation "invisibility" or an ability "teleportation"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purposes of closing this question, I will mention that the original question on RPG was [answered to my satisfaction by KorvinStarmast](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/71020/4563):

> *Dweomer*
>
> This is another word for magical effect that was used a great deal in 1e AD&D.
>
> "My class imbues a dweomer on an item."
>
> Example usage. (1e DMG page 52)
>
> > Carpet of flying: Carpets are the most stable of flying devices, and
> >     thus the most valuable. ...snip... While hovering or moving slowly
> >     they are ideal platforms for spell- or missile-casting ... snip...
> >     They are not so easily adapted to aerial melee, as passengers will
> >     tend to get knocked off the carpet and fall to the ground. Attempts to
> >     weave straps or seat belts into a flying carpet will generally destroy
> >     its **dweomer**.
>
> Wikitionary entry:
>
> > *dweomer* ‎Alternative spelling of dwimmer. (fantasy, games) The magical aura on an enchanted item; or more broadly, the aura of a magic spell having been cast while active.
>
> ['Tis from an auld wyrd](http://www.yourdictionary.com/) ...
>
> > dwimmer From Old English *ġedwimor*,
> >     *dwimor* dwimmer Noun (plural dwimmers) •(obsolete) Magic, sorcery, spell, occult art.

Answer (score 3):

As this question is still (surprisingly) open how about dumping *imbue* for *anoint* and using *elixir* for the noun.

> I anoint my rod of merriment with the elixir of rigidity.

Comment: Yes, you *imbue* an object *with* a power. So the direct object is, funnily enough, the object!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> Someone attaches a **__** to an object
>
> Someone assigns a **__** to an object
>
> Someone charges an object with **__**
>   ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
>
> Someone permeates an object with **__**
>
> Someone endows an object with **__**

Comment: I like all these verbs, but I also liked the verb that I had, and the question was more about getting a noun to fill in those blanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confustulating *imbue* with *endow*.

Someone endows an **endowment** on an object, giving it magic powers.

> [endow](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=endow)
>
> /ɪnˈdaʊ,ɛn-/
>
> verb
>
> verb: endow; 3rd person present: endows; past tense: endowed; past
>   participle: endowed; gerund or present participle: endowing
>
> 1. ...
>   2.
>
> provide with a quality, ability, or asset. "**he was endowed with
>   tremendous physical strength**"
>
> synonyms: provide, supply, furnish, equip, invest, give, present,
>   favour, bless, grace, award, gift, confer, bestow, enrich, arm;
>   literary endue  "nature endowed the human race with intelligence"

Answer (score 0):

This is probably silly of me to reply to a four-year-old post, but I'm writing a job ad for someone to help write educational materials for kids.  I want a writer who finds nearly any topic fascinating and can imbue that feeling into whatever he or she writes. I found this post when I was checking to be sure my usage of imbues meant what I intended, and I ended up with what I think is a great idea for what you were searching for!

My suggestion for your D&D game is

**"imbues an emotion"**

Not only is a great alliteration that will be fun to say as you play;), it really fits well with the meaning of imbue because nothing really soaks and saturates us as much as our emotions!  Plus, just like you have a reference list of what various spells do when cast, you can create a list of what various emotions do when imbued.  This should work perfectly for playing, and I bet it will be really fun to invent what effect various emotions have on the item or person who gets imbued!

Enjoy!
micheley